# reflect bootstrap failed:

Tags: android-studio, reflection, virtual-machine, space, android-13

I am trying to use reflection it work fine on android 12 and below android 12 but when i try for android 13 it gives me crash
reflect bootstrap failed:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at me.weishu.reflection.BootstrapClass.(BootstrapClass.java:27)
at me.weishu.reflection.BootstrapClass.exemptAll(BootstrapClass.java:72)
at me.weishu.reflection.Reflection.unseal(Reflection.java:35)

i am using code from this library

https://github.com/tiann/FreeReflection

mostly it ask for

`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: dalvik.system.VMRuntime.setHiddenApiExemptions [class [Ljava.lang.String;] at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2103)`

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue here, final solution:

- **Simple**: use [whulzz1993/RePublic](https://github.com/whulzz1993/RePublic) to instead [FreeReflection](https://github.com/tiann/FreeReflection)
- **Detail**: please refer my answer in [黑名单或深灰名单方法不生效](https://github.com/tiann/FreeReflection/issues/4)